# Pictures folder showing 39GB for 0 items! Please help?

Tags: macos, folders, graphics

new here and hoping some wiz can point me in the right direction....

- pictures folder showing 39Gb but there are no files in it
- trash is empty
- have tried rebooting
- searched everywhere on the net, no one seems to know whats up
- Mac OSX 10.6.8 on an old Macbook 13" 2007, 4Gb ram, 160gb HD
- HD is pretty much FULL so need this sorted coz things are grinding to a halt!

any help appreciated :)

Comment: who is showing 39GB ? which app?

Comment: Please show us a screenshot where you are seeing the system telling you 39GB.

Answer (score 1):

Since 10.6 doesn't have a Recovery HD you will want to install a second copy of the OS onto a USB drive and/or use the DVD install media to start the Mac and run Disk Utility to examine the filesystem.

Before that, make a backup of the Mac (or at least your critical files, photos, etc...) to be sure you don't make things worse. Disk Utility will sacrifice files to make the filesystem whole in some cases.

Also, you could boot into single user mode and run `/sbin/fsck -fy` without mounting the root filesystem as an alternative if you are comfortable with that level of sophistication with terminal.

Post back details if you get hung up or if these details aren't enough to go on.

Comment: Or you could run ls -al in terminal on the directory to see what invisible files are there.